# How can I find the source of a particular portion of markup in an Angular app?

Tags: html, angularjs, templates

I'm learning Angular on the fly while working on the front-end of a web app. I'm having to make some changes to the markup and because the final output comprises of many templates it is often difficult to find sources of some of the markup. Is there something similar to source maps, or at least comments for debug purposes?

Comment: Are the sources in variables or only strings ? If variables, you can put {{ theurl }} in the page in order to display the value without looking at the controller.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow… Please keep in mind that I am a relative noob to Angular.

Comment: Do you mean which bit of angular code is responsible for each bit of html you see?

Answer (score 0):

Just view source in the browser. Injected templates will be under something like `<ui-view style="ng-scope">` or similar.

Comment: "or similar" is the problem. It's inconsistent and sometimes a nightmare to find the source html.

Comment: You could name your tags with data attributes.. like `data-tagname="main"`.

Comment: Something like that might work when you're building a small app from scratch, though in that case you probably would know where everything is anyway. I'm dealing with a large app which I wasn't involved in developing from the beginning. Thanks anyway.